# An Even More Northern North America

Tags: environment, climate, geography, geology

If I move both the North and South American mainlands (meaning the islands stay right where they are) north by a latitude of five degrees, what kinds of climates would I be looking at?

Answer (score 2):

To put things simply, just take the actual climates and move them 5 degrees south. If you want a more accurate model it could take at least several hours to have something good. Temperatures are easier to predict than the changes in the rain pattern and this part is really hard to do.

Comment: Challenge me?  What are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnWDailey No, I think you misunderstood. The sentence is directed against people that would be tempted to flag the answer because they think it's bad. I'm just saying that if they think it's bad, they should make the effort of offering something better. On second thought, I will get rid of it because it could just confuse people.